# create complex sql query

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables :

TB1:

```
ID   Name     
1    R
2    F
3    B
```

TB2:

```
ID1     
1
2      
1      
2      
2
```

TB3:

```
ID1   Stat
1     20
2     10 
3     20
```

I need a SQL query to return below specification:

1. id , name from TB1 and Count of rows from TB2
2. the rows that stat=20 in TB3
3. Count of rows repeat in TB2

OUTPUT:

```
ID    Name    Count
1     R       2
3     B       0
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.id, a.name, count(b.id1) 
from table1 a join table3 c 
on a.id = c.id1 and c.stat = 20 
left join table2 b on a.id = b.id1 
group by a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TB1.ID,
       TB1.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TB2.ID1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Repeat
FROM   TB1 
       JOIN TB3
           ON TB1.ID = TB3.ID1
           AND TB3.STAT = 20
       LEFT JOIN TB2
           ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID1
GROUP BY TB1.ID,
       TB1.Name,
```